# How can I find the driver of syntek webcam for my laptop?

Tags: drivers, webcam, asus

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 BIT on a laptop Asus F5RL with a webcam syntek.

I can't find a driver for this device, .DEB or for compiling manually, so this webcam doesn't work.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the following:

Ubuntu 12.04 Syntek in-built webcam not detected

http://askubuntu.com/questions/145859/ubuntu-12-04-syntek-in-built-webcam-not-detected

Answer (score 0):

My comment above suggests that the device is there but mislabelled `/dev/video0` rather than `/dev/video1`. Check the link for more info...